# FxCop / Code Analysis with VS2010 Ultimate

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2010, optimization

I've getting some information about this, but I still can find a proper answer, I was asked recently in my company for this : "run a fxcop analysis on that code and tell me the results".

Ok, I have VS2010 Ultimate which has code analysis, but before making any comment, I browse it on the internet cause I want to implement the best choice...

So, let's say I'm gonna use the same rules on both analyzers:

- Should I recommend using one above the other?
- Should I say "hey, thats kinda old, let's use code analysis!"
- Should I get the same results on different computers? (for what I undersand, fxcop gives you some "points" and for what I've read, sometimes it gives you diff points on diff computers, I don't know about this with code analysis

Thanks, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

FxCop is mostly a "style" analyzer (it finds things documented in the [Framework Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx)).  It does *not* substitute for a full-blown static code analysis tool like the one in VS2010 Ultimate.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like a better option to use only code analysis